# get notification from hasura to an angular application

Tags: angular, push-notification, webhooks, hasura, graphql-subscriptions

Can you suggest me some guidelines to build an architecture to get notification from a hasura server to an angular application?

my use case is sumple:
i insert a document on hasura, the angular client should be notified by in icon on the toolbar

what kind of components do i need:

On the hasura side i guess i need "subscriptions", webhooks, push notification?

On the angular side what do i need to receive that event?
a serviceworker? others?

Another requirement is that the server shoul be used "tomorrow" from a mobile app as well (so should i use push notification instead of subscription?)

Can you give me some high level guidelines/suggestion to design such architecture?

Answer (score 1):

You should look for angular GraphQL client libs for Angular as hasura's API is done in GraphQL.

Hasura's website provides us with a [course/tutorial](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/angular-apollo/introduction/) on how to implement an interface to hasura's, using [Apollo Angular](https://apollo-angular.com/) as a GraphQL lib.

It is hard to advise on components and services you might use without a deeper understanding of the requirements of your application.